# How to make a proper SOAP request to Amadeus Enterprise Endpoints?

Tags: xml, postman

I have been trying to make a proper xml request to the Amadeus Enterprise Ws on postman but with no luck. I keep getting the following error:

```html
<soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring> 12|Presentation|soap message header incorrect</faultstring>
      <faultactor>SI:muxDZ2</faultactor>
</soap:Fault>
```

I guess there is something wrong with my headers, but I am not sure what that is because I have been finding and following examples as many as I can.

Here's my request headers:

```html
<soapenv:Header>
    <add:Action xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://webservices.amadeus.com/Hotel_MultiSingleAvailability_10.0</add:Action>
    <add:To xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://nodeD2.test.webservices.amadeus.com/xxxxxxxxx</add:To>
    <link:TransactionFlowLink xmlns:link="http://wsdl.amadeus.com/2010/06/ws/Link_v1"/>
    <oas:Security xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <oas:UsernameToken oas1:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <oas:Username>xxxxxxxx</oas:Username>
            <oas:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">xxxxxxxxxxxx</oas:Nonce>
            <oas:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">xxxxxxxxxxx</oas:Password>
            <oas1:Created>2024-02-25T03:00:15.115Z</oas1:Created>
        </oas:UsernameToken>
    </oas:Security>
    <AMA_SecurityHostedUser xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Security_v1">
        <UserID AgentDutyCode="SU" POS_Type="1" PseudoCityCode=office_id RequestorType="U"/>
    </AMA_SecurityHostedUser>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Can anyone help me to find out what is wrong with my codes? Thanks!!

Comment: You may be missing http headers.  Postman has a Control Panel that will give the actual HTTP message that is sent.  Compare the message in Control Panel to your code and check the differences.   Then modify you code to match Postman.